# How do I unit test a FastAPI endpoint with a File?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am writing a unit test for something similar to:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
import json

app = FastAPI()


class UploadPolarEndpoint(BaseModel):
    name: str
    loading_condition: str
    wings: bool
    centreboard: bool
    asymmetric: bool
    input_cols: list[str]


@app.patch("/edit_polar")
def edit_polar(polar_data: UploadPolarEndpoint = File(...)):
    return polar_data
```

This unit test used to work with pydantic v1, but in v2 it seems to have broken. I am trying to test it like:

```py
client = TestClient(app)

data = UploadPolarEndpoint(
    name="renamed_polar",
    loading_condition="BST",
    wings=False,
    centreboard=True,
    asymmetric=True,
    input_cols=["Speed", "TWS", "TWScs"],
)

response = client.patch(
    "/edit_polar",
    data={
        "polar_data": data.model_dump()
    }
)

assert response.status_code == 200
```

However it always returns as unprocessible entity:

```
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())

422
{'detail': [{'type': 'model_attributes_type', 'loc': ['body', 'polar_data'], 'msg': 'Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from', 'input': "{'name': 'renamed_polar', 'loading_condition': 'BST', 'wings': False, 'centreboard': True, 'asymmetric': True, 'input_cols': ['Speed', 'TWS', 'TWScs']}", 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/model_attributes_type'}]}
```

I have tried multiple combinations of using `data`, `json`, `files` and also using `model_dump` and `model_dump_json` but nothing seems to work. How do I unit test this endpoint?

Comment: You've assigned the parameter as being a `File`, but you're submitting a standard JSON body (and trying to assign it to a standard model as such when receiving it); are you sure the `File()` part is supposed to be there? (and if you need to assign it as being from a specific source (you shouldn't) using `Body()` seems more correct)